# Qt - QPixmap of QLabel don't update after long-running

Tags: c++, qt

I use `QLabel` to show frame captured by camera.

```
//subThread: capture frame from camera
...
m_videoCapture = new cv::VideoCapture(pipeline, CAP_GSTREAMER);

while(m_videoCapture.isOpened())
{
   m_videoCapture->read(m_frame);
   if (m_frame)
   {
       //callback method
       m_funcFrame(m_frame, pUser);
   }
}
```

```
//MainThread

//callback method--show image on QLabel
showImage(cv::Mat& frame)
{
   m_image = QImage(frame.data, frame.cols, frame.rows, frame.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
   QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(m_image).copy();
   m_pixmap = pixmap.scaled(width, height, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformat).copy;

  ui->m_label->setPixmap(m_pixmap);
}
```

it work fine but `QLabel`'s pixmap don't update any more on matter how I  move camera  after 5 or 6 hours.  I have to restart my application to let it back to normal.

Comment: How is showImage() called? It must only be executed in the main thread so you should use signals/slots for this task.

Comment: Are you sure `showImage` is actually called after 5-6 hours? Create a new label that displays the timestamp of the last call of `showImage` as normal text. I would suspect your method is not called at all because something else crashed.

Comment: @SebastianDietrich  I am sure `showImage` is actually called because  I added `qDebug` info in this method and  it printed  on every call.

Comment: @chehrlic  Using signals / slots will cause run out of memory because my plaform is jetson nano which havn't higher computing power